# How to hide a button if a textarea gets empty and show the button as soon as it's not empty anymore?

Tags: jquery, html, hide

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var textboxHomeValue = $('#post-textbox textarea');

    $(document).on('keyup, keydown', '[data-listener="textboxHome"]', textboxHome);
    function textboxHome(e) {
        if($.trim(textboxHomeValue).length > 0){
            $('#post-button-disabled').hide();
            $('#post-button').show();
        } else {
            $('#post-button-disabled').show();
            $('#post-button').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

The beginning works fine. As soon as I type something into the textarea, the button shows up but if I delete the text it won't disappear again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `$.trim` the **value** of your `textarea`, not the jQuery object containing your `textarea` :

```js
$(document).on('keyup', 'textarea', function() {
  if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0) {
    $('button').show();
  } else {
    $('button').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>I'm only here if the textarea is empty !</button>
```

Comment: @AyumiTakanashi No problem, don't forget to validate this answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to  use the [jQuery change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) Method

```
$("#yourTextarea").change(function(){
    //Check if empty or not and hide button if needed
});
```

To call your function:

```
$("#yourTextarea").change(textBoxHome);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```js
//Initially hide button
$('#btn').hide();

//Textarea keyup function
$('textarea[name=txtarea]').keyup(function(){
  if($.trim($(this).val()).length  <= 0)$('#btn').hide()
  else $('#btn').show()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="txtarea"></textarea>
<button  id ="btn">Button</button>
```